# Product expansion for $\zeta(s + \frac{1}{2})$

Tags: riemann-zeta, hadamard-product

The Hadamard Product for the Riemann zeta function is given by

$\zeta(s) = \frac{e^{[\ln(2\pi)-1-\gamma/2]s}}{2(s-1)\Gamma(1+\frac{s}{2})}\prod_{\rho}(1-\frac{s}{\rho})\exp(\frac{s}{\rho}),$

compare http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardProduct.html, where the infinite product is taken over all **non**trivial zeros, counting their multiplicity. From this it trivially follows that

$\zeta(s+\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{e^{[\ln(2\pi)-1-\gamma/2](s+\frac{1}{2})}}{2(s-\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(1+\frac{s+\frac{1}{2}}{2})}\prod_{\rho}(1-\frac{s+\frac{1}{2}}{\rho})\exp(\frac{s+\frac{1}{2}}{\rho})$.

But as the nontrivial zeros of $\zeta(s+\frac{1}{2})$ correspond one-to-one to the nontrivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$, the former ones being shifted $\frac{1}{2}$ to the left with respect to the latter ones, it may also, I guess, be written as

$\zeta(s+\frac{1}{2}) = \phi(s)\prod_{\rho}(1-\frac{s}{\rho-\frac{1}{2}})\exp(\frac{s}{\rho-\frac{1}{2}}),$

for some function $\phi(s)$, with the infinite product being taken over the exact same zeros as before. My question is now: What is $\phi(s)$ given by?, as a **closed** expression, i.e., with**out** any infinite product.

**Update** [as a result of the comments below]: To find $\phi(s)$, I need to evaluate the following infinite product:

$\prod_{\rho} \frac{(1-\frac{s+\frac{1}{2}}{\rho})\exp(\frac{s+\frac{1}{2}}{\rho})}{(1-\frac{s}{\rho-\frac{1}{2}})\exp(\frac{s}{\rho-\frac{1}{2}})} = \prod_{\rho} (1-\frac{1}{2\rho})\times\prod_{\rho}\exp(\frac{2\rho-2s-1}{2\rho(2\rho-1)}),$

here generally assuming that the ratio of two infinite products is the infinite product of ratios. The first product is some constant, but the second product is not. How can I evaluate that latter one?

Comment: By $\displaystyle\prod_\rho \frac{1-\frac{s+1/2}{\rho}}{1-\frac{s}{\rho-1/2}} = \prod_\rho \exp(...)$

Comment: I would like $\phi(s)$ given as a closed expression, just as for the Hadamard product.

Comment: What do you get for $\exp(\ldots)$ ?

Comment: The Hadamard product of $\zeta(s)$ isn't at all trivial. It follows from the functional equation and the density of zeros and it is equivalent to the Riemann explicit formula.

Comment: I am certainly not claiming that the Hadamard product is trivial. What I am claiming is that _knowing_ the Hadamard product, it is trivial to write $\zeta(s+\frac{1}{2})$ as infinite product as well - the second equation of mine above.

Comment: Then $\displaystyle \frac{1-\frac{s+1/2}{\rho}}{1-\frac{s}{\rho-1/2}}= ?$

Comment: This is embarrasing, but I suddenly realize that the answer to the last equation of yours is simply $1-\frac{1}{2\rho}$.

Comment: Yep. So the ratio of the two products (assuming it converges) is a constant

Comment: But it does not converge because $\sum_{\rho} {\vert \rho \vert}^{-1} = \infty$, I believe, for otherwise the Hadamard product could be written without exponentials, that is, using $p=0$ in Weierstrass' elementary factors, $E_{p}(s)$.

Comment: It does converge as $\lim_{T \to \infty} \prod_{|Im(\rho)| < T}$ (thanks to the [density of zeros](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#La_fonction_S.28T.29)). Otherwise you can use the $\exp(s\rho)$ regularization terms in the Hadamard product.

Comment: Thanks for these pointers of yours. I will now ponder their implications for the original question of mine.

Comment: ???? That's the answer.

Comment: Please forgive me, but so what? If the second infinite product cannot be written in terms of elementary functions (including here of course the gamma function, etc.), then it is of little use. If this infinite product was all I had in mind, then my original question would be almost trivial.

Comment: Your original question is trivial.

Comment: Sadly, I don't understand why it's trivial. If it really is trivial, then, I guess, providing a closed (i.e., no infinite product), explicit expression for $\phi(s)$ in terms of elementary functions should be a piece of cake.

Comment: Well $\zeta(s)$ isn't an elementary function. Your question was "why when we shift $s$ we obtain a different Hadamard product" the answer is "it is the same up to a constant".

Comment: Now I recommend showing $(s-1)\zeta(s)$ is entire and using the functional equation to show it has order $\le 1$. Thus $F(s) =\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}-\frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{\zeta(\rho)=0} (\frac{1}{s-\rho}+\frac{1}{\rho})$ is entire. The job is to show that $F$ is bounded and hence constant.

Comment: I really appreciate this extra input of yours. Unfortunately, I am a physicist with only the most basic knowledge about complex analysis: I know concepts like meromorphic functions, entire functions, poles, residues, the residue theorem, etc., and I understand how to derive the functional equation for $\zeta$, but I have no present knowledge of concepts like the order or the genus of entire functions. I guess I will have to study.

Comment: In the past I've found while I was searching information about $\zeta(s)$ an author, Arias de Reyna, that shares in arXiv some of his publications, with coauthors Brent and van de Lune, about $\zeta(s)$. I am not a professor, and I am not able to read those papers but I think that those papers have a high quality. Thus if you are interested in the theory of the Riemann Zeta function I recommend you these papers. Is not required a response of this comment, and good luck.

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest. Searching at arxiv.org for authors Reyna, Brent, and Lune, I find two articles. Unfortunately, although having only skimmed them, none of them seem to contain statements that I can readily use.

Answer (score 2):

I have now determined the function $\phi(s)$. It is given by

$\phi(s) = -\frac{\zeta(\frac{1}{2})\pi^{1+\frac{s}{2}}\sqrt{2}}{8(s-\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{3}{4})\Gamma(\frac{5}{4}+\frac{s}{2})}.$

The calculations leading to this result do not strike me as particularly trivial, as one of the commenters of my original question asserted.

Comment: It is once you know the product for $\zeta(s)$